# jQuery $.post basics

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just learning how to use jquery, and I'm beyond confused. Here's what I'm trying to do (for practice/learning purposes):

1. Take an input
2. Post the input into a div tag using jquery

Here's my code.. but it's not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(data) {
$.post("<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>", function(data) {
    $("#lol").innerHTML = data;
});
}
</script>

<form action="" onsubmit="test($(this.children()))" method="POST">
<input type="hidden"
    value="derp" />
<input type="text"
    name="herp" />
<a href="javascript:void(0)"
    onclick="test($(this).parent())">
    Submit
</a>
</form>
<div id="lol">...</div>
```

Some help/tutorial explanation would be absolutely wonderful. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to put the data from the form into your #lol div, or are you trying to put the server response into your #lol div?

Comment: Like Amber said you want to use `.load`, but also, is this the full code? It seems to me there is some PHP logic missing?

Comment: Right now I'm just trying to figure out how to put data into the div. Next step is query the database and return the result into the div. Mosselman, that's the thing. I have no idea.. I figure the php comes in when I need to handle a server response

Comment: You should get an error in the console. Have a look at `test($(this.children()))` compared to (correct) `test($(this).parent())`.

Comment: That's so weird. I just saw that there was an extra ')' (oops) but the JS console hasn't been telling me anything =/

Comment: Have you looked at the examples on http://docs.jquery.com/Post

Comment: I have but I can't seem to replicate them

Comment: don't use ajax on the same page.

Comment: Side-note, use `.html()` instead of `.innerHTML`, you have jQuery ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` variable is being misused. If you want to send data with your post request, which you do, you'll want something like this:

```
function test(post_data_array) {
    $.post(
        "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>",
        post_data_array,
        function(response_data) {
            $("#lol").innerHTML = data;
        }
    );
}
```

In your example, the form data isn't being sent at all. Hope this helps!

**jQuery $.post() reference:**
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/